# C++ istringstream range-based for loop has no begin member

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a basic REPL that parse for special characters entered by a user. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888022/split-string-by-single-spaces) post shows how to split on whitespace but I get this compiling error when I try to store the stringstream into the vector of strings.

```
repl.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
repl.cpp:52:25: error: range-based ‘for’ expression of type ‘std::__cxx11::basic_istringstream<char>’ has an ‘end’ member but not a ‘begin’
         for (string s : iss)
                         ^~~
repl.cpp:52:25: error: ‘std::ios_base::end’ cannot be used as a function
make: *** [repl.o] Error 1
```

Here is the full code below:

```
#include <cstdlib>                                                                                         
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    size_t pos;
    int pipe = 0;
    int pid = 0;
    vector <size_t> positions;
    vector <string> arguments;
    do  
    {   
        cout << "repl$ ";
        getline(cin, cmd);

        pos = cmd.find( "|", 0); 
        while ( pos != string::npos )
        {   
            positions.push_back(pos);
            pos = cmd.find( "|", pos+1);
            pipe += 1;
            pid += 1;
        }   

        istringstream iss(cmd);

        while (iss >> cmd)
            arguments.push_back(cmd);  

        for (string s : iss)
            cout << s << endl;
  
    } while (cmd != "q");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `for (string s : arguements)`?  Streams don't work like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a `std::istream_iterator<std::string>` to read successive strings.  Boost has a wrapper to create a pseudo-container representing the sequence of objects read from an `istream`; for example:

```
for (const auto& s : boost::range::istream_range<std::string>(iss))
    std::cout << s << '\n';
```

An alternative in this specific case would be to copy directly to an output iterator:

```
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>{iss},
          std::istream_iterator<std::string>{},
          std::ostream_iterator<std::string>{std::cout, '\n'});
```