# Read multiple lines fro text and store in a vector as objects

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++14

Good evening everyone,

I'm trying to read from a text file source with the following format:

```
   doomsday [villain]
   Doomsday is a fictional supervillain appearing in American comic books published by DC Comics.

   superman [hero]
   Superman is a fictional superhero appearing in American comic books published by DC Comics.
```

These are two entries. I need to extract the name, role and description so I can place it into an object e.g.

```
   DCCharacters newCharacter(characterName, characterRole, description);
```

My code so far:

```
ifstream fileToOpen(fileSrc);

if (fileToOpen.is_open()) {
    string line;
    string charName;
    string charRole;
    string charDesc;

    while (!fileToOpen.eof()) {

        getline(fileToOpen, line);
        charName = line;
        if (line == "") continue; // Skip blank lines

        getline(fileToOpen, line);
        charDescription = line;
        if (line == "") continue;

        DCCharacters newCharacter(characterName, characterRole, description);
        this->DCCharsVector.push_back(newCharacter);
    }
    // Close the file
     fileToOpen.close();
     }
 }
```

As you can see I can extract the character name and role in one line and the description in another, but I dont now how to seperate the name and role into two seperate variables to put them into the object like I need to.

I'm looking forward to any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split string by single spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888022/split-string-by-single-spaces)

Comment: You should check the return code of `getline()` before using the contents of `line`. You should consider to implement the `operator>>()` overloads for your class...

Answer (score 0):

[std::getline()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) has one more overload, which should solve your problem:

```
istream& getline (istream&  is, string& str, char delim);
```

If you use ' ' (space character) as delimiter, `std::getline()` will read only up to first space it sees.

So, your code could look like this:

```
if (fileToOpen.is_open()) 
{
    string line;
    string charName;
    string charRole;
    string charDesc;

    while (!fileToOpen.eof()) 
    {
        getline(fileToOpen, line, ' ');
        charName = line;
        if (line == "") continue; // Skip blank lines

        getline(fileToOpen, line);
        charRole = line; //possibly strip off '[]' before assigning
        if (line == "") continue; // Skip blank lines

        getline(fileToOpen, line);
        charDescription = line;
        if (line == "") continue;

        DCCharacters newCharacter(characterName, characterRole, description);
        DCCharsVector.push_back(newCharacter);
    }
// Close the file
    fileToOpen.close();
}
```

On a side note, you needlessly copy strings lots of times. You could pass `charName` etc. as argument to `std::getline()` and get rid of `line` variable.
Also, since you tagged `C++11`, you could use

```
DCCharsVector.emplace_back(characterName, characterRole, description)
```

to avoid creating temporary object.