# Extracting all words separated by non-alphabetical characters

Tags: c++

Given a string such as:

```
std::string word = "Hello World!it's@.-/sunday";
```

I want to extract all the words which are separated by non-alphabetical letters stored in a container like a vector, so for this case it would be:

```
Hello, World, it, s, sunday
```

My initial try was to use isalpha() along with an index count to substr() accordingly like so:

```
std::string word = "Hello World!it's@.-/sunday";
    int count = 0, index = 0; 
    std::string temp;  
    
     for (; count < word.length();count++){
        if (!isalpha(word[count])){
            temp = word.substr(index,count);
            index = count; 
        }
    }
```

But this does not work as I thought it would as the index does not update fast enough resulting in words mixed with non-alphabetical characters. Is there perhaps a function or a better way to extract said words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code. It constructs the words char by char.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
 
int main()
{
std::string phrase = "Hello World!it's@.-/sunday";
std::vector<std::string> words;  
std::string tmp;
 for (const char &c:phrase)
 {
        if (isalpha(c))
        {
            tmp.push_back(c);
        }
        else
        {
            words.push_back(tmp);
            tmp = "";
        }
 }
 if (!tmp.empty())
 {
     words.push_back(tmp);
 }
 
 for (const auto w : words)
 {
     std::cout << w << std::endl;
 }
 
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: is there any built in function for that in C++? i often requred this.

Comment: Yes you could use a regular expression to keep only alpha chars. See here for an example. https://regex101.com/r/3xHfeA/1

Answer (score 0):

one easy way is that **replace all the non-alphabetical char to space** than
**[split around space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888022/split-string-by-single-spaces)**.